# Calling functions from another class in Tkinter

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I have a class in a separate python script that I want to be linked to an external button in a canvas using Tkinter.  The current class now has frames, labels, and buttons and I can get it to pop-up when clicking my external button but none of the functions work when I put `root = Tk()` before `frame` in the data.py script.

```
import Tkinter as ttk
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import data


def XYevent():
    data.makeXY()


top = ttk.Tk()
C = ttk.Canvas(top, bg="white", height=250, width=300)
C.pack()
B=ttk.Button(C, text="Create XY Feature", command=XYevent)
B.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

This is my script so far but none of the functions are working in the pop-up window after clicking the button.  Am I missing a command in the canvas script?  data when run by itself works.

Here is the data.py script with the commands I want to link to a canvas window, eventually I want two buttons that open a different window that is related to the first but a different user option.

```
import arcpy
import Tkinter as ttk
import tkFileDialog
from arcpy import env
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox


class makeXY():
    def __init__(self):
        self.main()

    def XY(self,*args):
        arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(self.dbtable.get(), self.easting.get(), self.northing.get(),
                                       "Layers", self.prj.get())
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("Layers", self.New_Shapefile.get())
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Create ArcGIS feature", arcpy.GetMessages())

    def main(self):
        frame = ttk.Frame(root, padx=3, relief=SUNKEN, borderwidth=3)
        frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
        frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.labelVariable = IntVar()
        XYtitle = ttk.Label(frame, textvariable=self.labelVariable,
                        relief=GROOVE, fg="white", bg="#2C5E17", font=("Georgia", 12))
        XYtitle.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=5, sticky='EW', pady=5)
        self.labelVariable.set("Create A Feature For ArcGIS Using XY Data")


        # Creates an XY event
        self.dbtable = StringVar()
        self.dbtable_entry = ttk.Entry(frame, width=50, textvariable=self.dbtable).grid(column=1, row=2, sticky='WE')
        ttk.Button(frame, text="Input Table",command=lambda:self.dbtable.set
               (tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("All files",'*.*')]))).grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='WE')
        self.easting = StringVar()
        self.easting_entry = ttk.Entry(frame, width=20, textvariable=self.easting).grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=W)
        self.northing = StringVar()
        self.northing_entry = ttk.Entry(frame, width=20, textvariable=self.northing).grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=W)
        self.prj = StringVar()
        ttk.Button(frame, text="Projection File",command=lambda:self.prj.set
               (tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Project File",'.prj')]))).grid(row=5, column=2, sticky='WE')
        ttk.Entry(frame, width=50, textvariable=self.prj).grid(column=1, row=5, sticky='WE')
        self.New_Shapefile = StringVar()
        ttk.Entry(frame, width=50, textvariable=self.New_Shapefile).grid(column=1, row=6, sticky='WE')
        ttk.Button(frame, text="Output Feature",
                    command=lambda:self.New_Shapefile.set
               (tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=[("Feature Datasets", {'.shp','.gdb','.mdb'})]))).grid(row=6, column=2, sticky='WE')

       ttk.Button(frame, text="Create Feature", command=self.XY).grid(column=1, row=7, sticky=W)
       ttk.Label(frame, text="Input table with XY data: ").grid(column=0,row=2, sticky=W)
       ttk.Label(frame, text="Enter X (easting) field name: ").grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=W)
       ttk.Label(frame, text="Enter Y (northing) field name: ").grid(column=0, row=4, sticky=W)
       ttk.Label(frame, text="Enter projection file: ").grid(column=0, row=5, sticky=W)
       ttk.Label(frame, text="Feature output (shapefile, geodatabase):").grid(column=0, row=6, sticky=W)

       root.bind('<Return>', self.XY)

if __name__== "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.option_add("*Background", "#EBF1E8")
    root.option_add("*Entry.Background", "white")
    root.option_add("*Button.Background", "#afc8a4")
    root.option_add("*Label.Font", "helvetica 10")
    root.option_add("*Button.Font", "helvetica 9")
    root.title("XY Data to ArcGIS")
    client = makeXY()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have no idea what XY_Tk contains so don't know what it is supposed to do  I just answered a similar question at [Adding or deleting tkinter widgets from within other modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27019697/adding-or-deleting-tkinter-widgets-from-within-other-modules) which might help.

Comment: I added the original script to my question for clarification and changed XY_Tk.py to data.py.  I also tried the advice in your post but still could not make the button call the `makeXY()` class.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by taking out

```
root.bind()
```

and

```
if __name__ == "__main__"
```

from the class and used

```
ttk.mainloop()
```

in the script that calls the class.

Here is my working main script with the buttons that call two classes XYdata.py and selectfeature.py:

```
import Tkinter as ttk
import tkFileDialog
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import XYdata
from XYdata import *
import selectfeature
from selectfeature import *


def XYevent():
    XY.main()

def select():
    s.main()

root = ttk.Tk()
root.geometry("650x275+500+100")
root.option_add("*Background", "#EBF1E8")
root.option_add("*Entry.Background", "white")
root.option_add("*Button.Background", "#afc8a4")
root.option_add("*Label.Font", "helvetica 10")
root.option_add("*Button.Font", "helvetica 9")
root.title("Create Point Features for ArcGIS")

myframe = ttk.Frame(root,relief="groove",bd=1)
myframe.place(x=7, y=5, width=635, height=175)

canvas = ttk.Canvas(myframe)
frame = ttk.Frame(canvas)
canvas.pack(side="left", fill=BOTH)


canvaslbl= Label(canvas,text=' Create features for ArcGIS using two button options'),
             font=("Georgia", 12), justify=LEFT)
canvaslbl.pack()
canvas.create_window((0,0), window=frame, anchor='nw')
frame.bind("<Return>", XYevent)

b1 = ttk.Button(root, command=XYevent, text="XY Feature Class",fg="white",bg="#39442C", font=("helvetica", 10)) 
b1.place(x = 125, y = 210, width=180, height=40)
b2 = ttk.Button(root, command=select, text="Selection Feature Class",fg="white", bg="#39442C", font=("helvetica", 10))
b2.place(x = 350, y = 210, width=180, height=40)

XY = XYdata.makeXY(ttk, root)
s = selectfeature.selection(ttk, root)
ttk.mainloop()
```